# Can I choose to die instead of rolling death saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-death

In some circumstances, dying immediately might be useful (such as if I want to be restored by *revivify* next round) so as to qualify as a dead creature instead of a dying one.

Is this allowed?

Comment: Are there more circumstances where this is useful? I ask because restoration by revivify seems a lot more costly than restoration by any other lower-level healing method.

Comment: @Icyfire there are some benefits to a Blood Hunter if an ally dies rather than is just dying (say a zealot for example, who doesn't care that much about dying). Although blood hunter is homebrew...

Comment: Right, the death of the comrade enrages the other party members, who then kick butt.  Then you rez the comrade.  Like Phil Coulson. What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 26):

## No.

As an unstable creature, you cannot do anything aside from rolling Death Saving Throws. Just like in real life, you couldn't just die, out of the blue.

> Whenever you start your turn with 0 hit points, **you
> must make a special saving throw**, called a death saving
> throw, to determine whether you creep closer to death
> or hang onto life.

However, your teammates or pets or anything else can attack you to cause you to fail said Death Saving Throws.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77344/discussion-on-answer-by-bluemoon93-can-i-choose-to-die-instead-of-rolling-death).